# How to Jump from one loop to another while executing

Tags: arduino-uno

For my program I have to sense 3 inputs (`A1`, `A2` and `A3` in Arduino). If any one or two or more signals become zero (low), it goes in different case as per below program.

However, I want to reset the Arduino when all signals become high again. Therefore I have to again write another program `loop2()`.

So how can I exit from one loop and get into another loop. If I have to use `goto`, please tell me how to use it?

The Arduino program given below.

```
const int analogPin1 = A1;
const int analogPin2 = A2;
const int analogPin3 = A3;
const int ledPin = 13;
const int ledPin2 = 7;      
const int  thresold = 400; 
unsigned int x1,x2,x3,fault = 0;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void Config()
{
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("ATE0r");
    Response();
    Serial.print("ATr");
    Response();
    Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1r");
    Response();
    Serial.print("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0r");
    Response();
}

void Response()
{
    int count = 0;
    Serial.println();
    while(1)
    {
        if(Serial.available())
        {
            char data =Serial.read();
            if(data == 'K'){Serial.println("OK");break;}
            if(data == 'R'){Serial.println("GSM Not Working");break;}
        }
        count++;
        delay(10);
        if(count == 1000){Serial.println("GSM not Found");break;}

    }
}

void loop()
{
    int analogValue1 = analogRead(analogPin1);
    int analogValue2 = analogRead(analogPin2);
    int analogValue3 = analogRead(analogPin3);



    if (analogValue1 < thresold) 
    { x1=1;
        fault=x1;
    }
    if (analogValue2 < thresold)
    {  x2=x1+3;
        fault=x2;
    }
    if (analogValue3 < thresold)
    {  x3=x1+x2+5;
        fault=x3;
    }

    switch(fault)
    {
    case 1:

        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);         
        Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+919512700997\"\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("PHASE 1 HAS GONE");   
        delay(1000);
        Serial.write(0x1A);
        delay(1000);
        loop2();
        break;

    case 3:

        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);         
        Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+919512700997\"\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("2 HAS GONE");   
        delay(1000);
        Serial.write(0x1A);
        delay(1000);
        break;

    case 4:
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);         
        Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+919512700997\"\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("1 AND 2 HAS GONE");   
        delay(1000);
        Serial.write(0x1A);
        delay(1000);
        break;

    case 5:

        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);         
        Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+919512700997\"\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("3 HAS GONE");   
        delay(1000);
        Serial.write(0x1A);
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0");
        break;

    case 6:

        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);         
        Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+919512700997\"\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("1 AND 3 HAS GONE");   
        delay(1000);
        Serial.write(0x1A);
        delay(1000);
        break;

    case 8:

        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);         
        Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+919512700997\"\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("2 AND 3 HAS GONE");   
        delay(1000);
        Serial.write(0x1A);
        delay(1000);
        break;

    case 10:

        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);         
        Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+919512700997\"\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("ALL 3 HAS GONE");   
        delay(1000);
        Serial.write(0x1A);
        delay(1000);
        break;


    default:
        x1,x2,x3,fault=0;
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        break;

    }

    x1,x2,x3,fault=0;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    do
    {  
        int analogValue1 = analogRead(analogPin1);
        int analogValue2 = analogRead(analogPin2);
        int analogValue3 = analogRead(analogPin3);
    }
    while ( analogValue1 < thresold || analogValue2 < thresold || analogValue3 < thresold );


}

do
{  
    int analogValue1 = analogRead(analogPin1);
    int analogValue2 = analogRead(analogPin2);
    int analogValue3 = analogRead(analogPin3);
}
while (( analogValue1 > th) && (analogValue2 > th) && (analogValue3 > th));

}

void loop2()
{ 
    if (( analogValue1 > th) && (analogValue2 > th) && (analogValue3 > th)) 
    {

        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        Serial.begin(9600);   
        Serial.print("\r");
        delay(1000);                  
        Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+919512700997\"\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("Nikunjsinh2");   
        delay(1000);
        Serial.write(0x1A);
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("\r");
        delay(1000); 
        Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+919712554766\"\r");    
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print("Nikunjsinh2");   
        delay(1000);
        Serial.write(0x1A);
        delay(1000);

        do
        {  
            int analogValue1 = analogRead(analogPin1);
            int analogValue2 = analogRead(analogPin2);
            int analogValue3 = analogRead(analogPin3);
        }
        while (( analogValue1 > th) && (analogValue2 > th) && (analogValue3 > th));
    }
}
```

Comment: `x1,x2,x3,fault=0;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Also, with `do  { int analogValue1 = ...}` you are creating new variables that only exist inside the loop body. Remove the `int` s.

Comment: you can use `goto` in arduino to hop around labels. serious/team programmers might cringe, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear from your question you intuitively know this program will not perform as desired.  Simply put, if you do not check all states during every loop, you can not possibly react to all possibilities.  Therefore you can only have 1 loop.  Get rid of the other loops.

> ...but i want to reset arduino when all signal becomes again high...

This statement identifies what is missing.  You need a temporal aspect to the loop in order to "remember" that all signal(s) were not high on the previous loop and now in the current loop they are all high.

Programmers commonly refer to this feature as a [Finite State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).  A way to "remember" what state the loop was in the last time it was executed.  And a way to know what state(s) is(are) next possible.

If all you need to remember is that not all 3 inputs were high the last time through the loop, your state machine only needs the one value.  And that value only needs to be a zero or one.